# Remove author and author_url from the Wordpress oembed json link

Tags: wordpress, oembed

I've noticed that Wordpress generates 2 links in header. They contain some oembed arguments.

This look like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="......">
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href=".......">

{
      "version": "1.0",
      "provider_name": "Website Name",
      "provider_url": "http://example.com",
      "author_name": "admin",
      "author_url": "http://example.com/author/admin/",
      "title": "",
      "type": "rich",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 338,
      "html": "long string of html"
    }
```

I know I can disable those links but I would like to keep them and to remove only the author_name and author_url.

Is there a way I can do that?

I hope you can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Keep the rel links and filter the array data:

```
function filter_oembed_response_data_author( $data, $post, $width, $height ) {
    //print_r($data);
    unset($data['author_name']);
    unset($data['author_url']);
    return $data;
};
add_filter( 'oembed_response_data', 'filter_oembed_response_data_author', 10, 4 );
```

You can go to one of your rel link, uncomment print_r and manipolate the $data array to add, edit or remove entries.

Comment: Works perfectly fine.